# awk: compute min/max values for multi-column data using big number of input files

Tags: awk

I am dealing with the post-processing of big number of csv data files located in the distinct directories. Each csv file has the following 3 column format:

```
ID, POP, dG
1, 24, -6.8100
2, 22, -6.7900
3, 11, -6.6800
4, 18, -6.1100
5, 5, -6.0700
6, 1, -6.0600
7, 11, -6.0300
8, 36, -6.0100
```

The following bash function incorporates awk code that computes min for dG (the 3rd column, which is always negative float number) as well as max value for POP (the 2nd column 2, which is positive) values for **ALL processed CSVs at once** and stores it in new bash variables highestPOP lowestDG used by second awk script (not considered here):

```
home="$PWD"
# folder with the outputs
rescore="${home}"/rescore 
# folder with the folders to analyse
storage="${home}"/results_bench
cd "${storage}"
# pattern of the csv file located inside each of sub-directory of "${storage}"
str='*str1.csv'
rescore_data4 () {
str_name=$(basename "${str}" .csv)
mkdir -p "${rescore}"/"${str_name}"
# 1- calculate max POP and dGmin for ALL rescored CSVs at once
read highestPOP lowestDG < <(
    awk -F ', ' '
        FNR == 1 {
            next
            }
        NR == 2 || $2 > popMAX {popMAX = $2}
        NR == 2 || $3 < dGmin  {dGmin  = $3}
        END {printf "%d %.2f\n", popMAX, dGmin}
    ' "${storage}"/*_*_*/${str}
)
#
# 2- run rescoring routine using the min/max values
awk -F', *' -v OFS=', ' -v highest_POP="${highestPOP}" -v lowest_dG="${lowestDG}" '
   ... some awk code
'
}
```

In the first awk script $str is the glob mask of the target csv file located in distinct directories (matching glob pattern "*_*_*")
While this generally works, there is a bug in the first AWK code (used to calculate min/ max values for ALL processed CSVs)  : sometimes the value of the lowestDG can not be computed in the case of a big number of input CSVs/ contained many lines. The problem always related to calculating of dg variable (Which always negative), the script reports dg=0.000, which is not correct.

To resolve the issue I tried to modify AWK code, defining two new variables (with min and max values) at the begining and then compare each value in the column to them:

```
   read highestPOP lowestDG < <(
    awk -F ', ' '
        FNR == 1 {
            dGmin = ""                              # initialize the min value
            POPmax = ""   
            next
            }
        NR == 2 || POPmax == "" || $2 > POPmax {POPmax = $2 }
        NR == 2 || dGmin == "" || $3 < dGmin  {dGmin  = $3 }
        END {printf "%d %.2f\n", POPmax, dGmin}
    ' "${storage}"/*_*_*/${str}
)
```

Now, technically it works but it seems that the second sollution does not report min and max values correctly. How the awk script may be fixed correcly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `awk` to calculate `max`/`min` across a range of files, simply provide those files on the command line as input to an `awk` script

```
awk -F, '
    ($2+0 > POP+0 || POP == "") && $1+0 > 0 { POP = $2 }
    ($3+0 < dG+0 || dG == "") && $1+0 > 0 { dG = $3 }
    END { print POP, dG }
' file1 file2 file3...
```

(This can also be written as a one-liner simply by concatenating all the lines, but it's way less readable.)

Let's break down one line. The pattern style is *expression* `{` *action* `}` and either part is optional. The expression here is looking for a larger value for `POP` on any line where the `ID` is a numeric non-zero

```
($2+0 > POP+0 || POP == "") && $1+0 > 0 { POP = $2 }

$2+0 > POP+0    # Is the numeric values of $2 more than the numeric value of POP
||              # OR
POP == ""       # Is POP the empty string (possibly unset)
```

If at least one of these is `true` then we also require the next condition

```
$1+0 > 0        # Is the numeric value of $1 greater than zero ("skip the header")
```

Then...

```
{ POP = $2 }    # Assign the numeric value of $2 to POP
```

The loop is then repeated for every line in every file. At the end of the last file the `END` construct is executed, which prints out the resulting two values.

Notice that only during comparisons are the values in the `awk` loop converted to numbers. At all other times they are just strings, so there is no loss of precision.

With `bash` you can assign variables to these outputs easily enough, allowing the unwanted whitespace to be discarded as a side-effect

```
read pop dg < <(awk ...)
```

For a very large number of files, such that a glob expansion fails,  the standard `find` approach should suffice, feeding the contents of the files into `awk` as *STDIN* instead of listing them on the command line

```
find "${storage}" -type f -name 'target_file.csv' -exec cat {} + | awk '...'
```

Comment: thank you very much for this as well as these explanations! Briefly it works like the first version of the awk script shown in my first topic but do the job correctly without any errors! I suppose the fix was achived via adding zero to each term, wasn't it? Cheers

Comment: @HotJAMS your version read each value as a number. Mine reads them as strings, so no loss of precision

Comment: Right, thank you so much again!

Comment: I've just finished a second round of tests using 18000 input csv filles :-) While it worked well with 3000 csvs, with huge number of files there is still an error in the calculation of min/max values for the both columns... may you propose some fix ? :-)

Comment: line 275: /usr/local/bin/awk: Argument list too long

Comment: so it seems that it does not accept all CSV filles at once via awk -F, '
    ' "${storage}"/*_*_*/target_file.csv assuming that I am dealing with 18000 directories now( the same with 4000 directories worted OK!)

Comment: the line 275 is directly is related to your AWK code (integrated to my bashworkflow), possible the last part where I load all CSVs at once: ${storage}"/***/target_file.csv

Comment: Answer updated with a standard solution for you

Comment: for 2000 it works but for 18000 filles it gives : line 275: /usr/bin/find: Argument list too long. :-)

Comment: for the test I reduced the number of the CSV to something aroung 4000 and your last solution is works.. can't understand why this happens so ...

Comment: The last solution would work with millions of files

Comment: ah just fixed small bug in the find. does it means that find "${storage}" -type f -name *keyword.csv -exec cat {} + | awk -F, ' ... '    will apply awk code on any file located in any sub-directories of "${storage}" (this was actually the issue since each csv is located within sub-directory!), whichj matching the glob pattern *keyword.csv ?

Comment: There's no bug in my `find`. Quote your pattern so that the shell doesn't attempt to expand it to match files in your current directory.

Comment: yes, sorry this was me who made the bug in the last solluion. BTW does it mean that with the properly quoted variables the command  should be: find "${storage}" -type f -name "${str}" -exec cat {} + | awk -F, '...' where $str='*keyword.csv'

Comment: That would work. (You don't need the curly brackets for `"$str"`)