# bash: calculate number of the directories

Tags: bash

As a part of my bash routine, I am trying to locate number of subdirectories located in the directory $storage and assosiate it to some variable, which will be used in the same script

```
number_dirs=$(ls -ld "${storage}"/* | wc -l)
  printf >&2 '%s is the number of the directories... ' "${number_dirs}" ;sleep 0.2
  printf >&2 "Keep calm!\n"
```

this works fine with the number of dirs around 2-4K but does not work with the huge number.  How I could use find command in the same way instead?

Comment: In [your earlier question](https://superuser.com/q/1649889/332907) you seemed to be wanting to search directories in [the entire tree](https://superuser.com/questions/1649889/awk-compute-min-max-values-for-multi-column-data-using-big-number-of-input-file#comment2526657_1649895) underneath `$storage` (you were using `$storage/**/` type constructs). The question you've asked here (and the answers) are only counting directories immediately underneath `$storage` rather than directories underneath directories (etc.) underneath `$storage`. Is that intentional?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Indeed, this time I just need to count the number of the directories located within $storage, thus ignoring possible subdirectories... so the proposed here answer works very well :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple scan with `find` would be:

```
number_dirs=$(find ${storage} -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | wc -l)
```

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
# store all the dir names in an array
dirs=( "${storage}"/*/ )

num_dirs=${#dirs[@]}
```

The trailing slash in the glob pattern restricts the results to only directories.

Answer (score 0):

#### Analysis

Note your `ls -ld "${storage}"/* | wc -l` is not restricted to directories; i.e. `ls` will list non-directories in `$storage` as well, `wc` will count them. Consider `"${storage}"/*/` (note the trailing slash) that will list directories and symlinks to directories, unless there is no match. If there is no match the `/*/` part will stay literal. Research what `shopt -s failglob` and `shopt -s nullglob` do.

Your command does not list deeper subdirectories, I assume this behavior is what you want.

Your command does not normally list hidden directories (with names starting with a dot). If you are interested in them, research `shopt -s dotglob`.

If `"${storage}"/*/` expands to huge number of words then you will get `argument list too long`. This is because `ls` is an external executable that needs to be called with array of arguments and [there's a limit for this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/45583/108618).

---

#### Shell can do this

You can let the shell count directories for you:

```
(shopt -s nullglob && set -- "${storage}"/*/ && echo "$#")
```

`set --` will store all the names as positional parameters, then `echo "$#"` will print the number. `set` is a builtin, it should not suffer from `argument list too long`. I deliberately used a subshell so the positional parameters of the current shell are not affected. I could use a separate array (like [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1651484/432690) does), but there's a potential problem. Bash allows you to set a huge number of positional parameters. On one hand it's good, since you want to count a huge number of directories. On the other hand the parameters need to be stored in memory as strings, even if you only want their count.

Note if you do this:

```
number_dirs=$(shopt -s nullglob && set -- "${storage}"/*/ && echo "$#")
```

then the inside of `$()` is executed in a subshell anyway, so you don't need additional parentheses. You may choose to use an array inside the subshell. In any case the subshell will exit immediately after `echo` and the memory will be released as soon as possible. But if you do this:

```
dirs=( "${storage}"/*/ )
num_dirs=${#dirs[@]}
```

and if you don't `unset dirs` then the array will become a burden. A subshell that dies right away and releases the memory is better than a memory-consuming array you may forget to unset.

One way or another all the expanded words need to be stored (if only temporarily in a subshell) before you get their count. For this reason you may prefer `find` that allows `wc` to count on the fly.

---

#### Or `find` + `wc`

A basic solution is in [yet another answer](https://superuser.com/a/1651478/432690) where the main point is `-type d`. The idea (with [proper quoting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618)):

```
find "$storage" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | wc -l
```

may fail because:

- `-maxdepth` and `-mindepth` are not portable;
- directory names may contain newline characters that will make `wc -l` miscount.

If your `find` supports `-printf` (so it most likely supports `-maxdepth` and `-mindepth`) then you can solve the latter problem by printing single bytes and counting them:

```
find "$storage" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf a | wc -c
```

where `a` is an arbitrary one-byte character.

A portable (but somewhat slower) solution is like this:

```bsh
( cd -- "$storage"/ && find . -type d ! -name . -prune -exec sh -c '
    for i do printf a; done
' find-sh {} + | wc -c )
```

The subshell makes `cd` not affect the current working directory of the current shell. I used `cd -- "$storage"/` first because it allows me to refer to `$storage` as `.` later and therefore easily exclude it without pruning. Without `cd` I would need to use something like `! -path "$storage"`, but then `find` would interpret `$storage` as a pattern; so this could fail in general.

On the other hand if you are permitted to `r`ead the directory but not to e`x`ecute (`cd` into, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21252/108618)) then `cd` will not work, while solutions without `cd` may.

---

#### Notes

- In `cd -- "$storage"/` the [double dash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/108618) and the trailing slash make paths like `-foo` or even `-` be interpreted as actual pathnames.
- `find-sh` is explained here: [*What is the second sh in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh`?*](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690).
- If you don't want to count hidden directories, add `! -name '.*'` after `-prune`.
- `-type d` does not match symlinks to directories. For comparison: shell globbing patterns like `*/` do match them.
- If you want to descend into subdirectories and count the entire subtree, omit `-prune`.
- `shopt` is not portable. I know no straightforward way to do in pure `sh` what `shopt -s nullglob` does in Bash. Your question is tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), so this should not be a problem.